# Google Admin SDK - add group to another group using Java client API

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

I can add a member to a Google Group like this:

```
directory.members().insert(<groupKey>, <member>).execute()
```

If I want to add a *group* to the group instead of a `member`, how do I do it? I can retrieve a Group reference like this:

```
Group myGroup = directory.groups().get(myGroupKey).execute();
```

... so how do I add it to a specified group?

Comment: Have you checked this documentation about [Add a group to another group](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167100?hl=en) in Gsuite?

Comment: @Jess, yes thanks, that's how to do it in the admin console. I need a programmatic way.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no documented way to add a nested group using Admin SDK.